# Can I have the XML in the log when sending FastInfoset request with Apache CXF?

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, jax-ws, fastinfoset

I need to to have the requests and responses in the logs of the application but the requests sent by Apache CXF are in FastInfoset (Content-Type: application/fastinfoset) which results in the log of the request and response being unreadable (since it's binary). Is there a way around that so that I keep FastInfoset messages (for performance reasons) but I get proper XML in the logs?

Here is the CXF configuration I have right now, if that helps:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">

    <bean id="logInbound" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor" />
    <bean id="logOutbound" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor" />

    <cxf:bus>
        <cxf:inInterceptors>
            <ref bean="logInbound" />
        </cxf:inInterceptors>
        <cxf:outInterceptors>
            <ref bean="logOutbound" />
        </cxf:outInterceptors>
        <cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
            <ref bean="logOutbound" />
        </cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
        <cxf:inFaultInterceptors>
            <ref bean="logInbound" />
        </cxf:inFaultInterceptors>
    </cxf:bus>
</beans>
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3):

I have taken a look at [LoggingInInterceptor.logInputStream](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.cxf/cxf-core/3.1.1/org/apache/cxf/interceptor/LoggingInInterceptor.java#LoggingInInterceptor.logInputStream%28org.apache.cxf.message.Message%2Cjava.io.InputStream%2Corg.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingMessage%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%29) and it seems that it does not support fastinfoset. But you can use a custom [interceptor](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html) instead of  `LoggingInInterceptor` and `LoggingOutInterceptor` to extract the payload, decode it, and log the original message.

```
public class CustomInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {
    public CustomInterceptor () {
        super(Phase.RECEIVE);
    }

    public void handleMessage(Message message) {
        //Get the message body into payload[] and set a new non-consumed  inputStream into Message
        InputStream in = message.getContent(InputStream.class);
        byte payload[] = IOUtils.readBytesFromStream(in);
        ByteArrayInputStream bin = new ByteArrayInputStream(payload);
        message.setContent(InputStream.class, bin);

        //Decode from FastInfoset and write the payload in your preferred log system
        OutputStream out = System.out 
        decodeFI(in,out);

    }

    public void handleFault(Message messageParam) {
        //Invoked when interceptor fails
        //Exception e = message.getContent(Exception.class);
    }
}
```

Replace in the XML file

```
<bean id="logInbound" class="test.CustomInterceptor" />
<bean id="logOutbound" class="test.CustomInterceptor" />
```

---

Finding an example of how to decode a FastInfoset has not been easy. Try this using DOM and FastInfoset-1.2.12.jar. In this [repo](https://github.com/pbielicki/fastinfoset-java/tree/master/samples/src/main/java/samples) you have several examples using sTAX and SAX

```
public void decodeFI(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws Exception{
    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();

    DOMDocumentParser parser = new DOMDocumentParser();
    parser.parse(doc, in);

    // write the content into xml file
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(out);
    transformer.transform(source, result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this looks great we are going to test it.

Comment: I sadly didn't had the time to test this, I'll validate when I would be able to but I did accorded you the bounty as it is a great response.